# how to make a stack trace as in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, stack-trace

zend framework how to do a stack trace?
Stack trace:

```
# 0 C: \ apache \ www \ itransition \ library \ Zend \ Controller \ Front.php (954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard-> dispatch (Object (Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object (Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
# 1 C: \ apache \ www \ itransition \ library \ Zend \ Application \ Bootstrap \ Bootstrap.php (97): Zend_Controller_Front-> dispatch ()
# 2 C: \ apache \ www \ itransition \ library \ Zend \ Application.php (366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap-> run ()
# 3 C: \ apache \ www \ itransition \ index.php (26): Zend_Application-> run ()
# 4 {main}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By catching a thrown exception, you can use [`Exception::getTraceAsString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php)

```
try
{
    throw new Exception('Just testing...');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```